# Is my code inefficient or is the task just large?

Tags: java, performance, audio

recently I started taking AP Computer Science. I am working on a project that takes two sound files and overlays them. The project itself is not very hard and I already got it done, but I am not sure if my code is inefficient or if it is just processing a large task. When I tested the code I used two small .wav files of sizes 390KB and 1.9MB. It worked fine with them. Now I am trying to overlay files of sizes 25.8MB and 30.6MB. BlueJ encountered a memory error so I increased the memory allocation. However I feel as if there is something wrong with my code and it is running inefficiently. So tell me, is my code just taking on a large task or is there a way (using the provided classes and the knowledge of a student with about 2 weeks of computer science classes and some informal background) to make the code more efficient?

Here is my code:

```
import sounds.*;
import sounds.Sample;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Overlay
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        APSoundClip clip1 = new APSoundClip("Mitch_Murder_-_Guile_39_s_Theme.wav");
        APSoundClip clip2 = new APSoundClip("Darude_-_Sandstorm_80s_Version.wav");

        APSoundClip greaterClip;
        APSoundClip lesserClip;

        if (clip1.getLength() > clip2.getLength())
        {
            greaterClip = clip1;
            lesserClip = clip2;
        }
        else
        {
            greaterClip = clip2;
            lesserClip = clip1;
        }

        APSoundClip clipNew = new APSoundClip(greaterClip.getLength());
        Sample sampleCombo = new Sample();
        System.out.println(greaterClip.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < greaterClip.getLength() - 1; i++)
        {
            int val1;
            int val2;

            Sample sample1 = greaterClip.getSample(i);
            val1 = sample1.getValue();

            if (i < lesserClip.getLength())
            {
                Sample sample2 = lesserClip.getSample(i);
                val2 = sample2.getValue();
            }
            else
            {
                val2 = 0;
            }
            sampleCombo.setValue(val1 + val2);

            clipNew.setSample(i, sampleCombo);
        }

        clipNew.draw();
        clipNew.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your code is inefficient, but i've noticed that you're using one value of the greater clip, because your counter `i` goes from `0` to `length - 2`, instead of to `length - 1`.

Comment: I'm guessing the memory-intense part of the code is outside of what you showed us, probably in one of the library functions that you're using. You should use a profiling tool like [Oracle Mission Control](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/oracle-java-mission-control-the-ultimate-guide.html) which will help you find the exact bottlenecks automatically.

Comment: What did you increase the memory limit to? It presumably does need to be a bit bigger than the two files.

Comment: @immibis I went into bluej.defs and changed `bluej.vm.args=-ea -Djavafx.macosx.embedded=true` to `bluej.vm.args=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`. I just tried running the code again and even with the whole GB of memory it still returned an overflow error.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything funky. Should be fine to me

Comment: Your code could be shorter, and a bit betther though (but that's a separate matter)

Answer (score 1):

There primary problem is that your code needs enough memory to hold 3 clips in memory.  And it is likely going to need more heap space than that, due to the overheads that are incurred when you have to read / decompress a data stream whose (uncompressed) size you don't know.

Unfortunately there is not a lot you can do about that using the `APSoundClip` class.  That is the way it is designed to work, it appears.  (Its goal is to be easy to use for teaching  Java ... not to be the worlds most memory efficient sound processing library.)

Even so, the time to create and play the output clip should be roughly proportional to the length of the longest of the input clips.  If you are seeing times that are much longer than would be expected, it is possible that your heap is (still) too small.  (When a heap is too close to full of data that can't be GC'ed you can get some pretty horrible performance.)

---

> So tell me ... is there a way (using the provided classes and the knowledge of a student with about 2 weeks of computer science classes and some informal background) to make the code more efficient?

Frankly, probably no.  The solution would entail:

1. throwing away your existing code (probably),
2. finding a Java sound library that allows to read, process and write the sound clips as streams; i.e. keeping only a small section of each clip in memory at any one time, and
3. rewrite your code to use that.

Unless you have a burning desire (and lots of time on your hands) I'd advise doing something else.

Comment: It's not just taking time, it's also throwing a `StackOverflowError` even with 1 gig, OP said. Even with the three clips in memory, memory usage should not exceed 100-110MB from what I see here

Comment: The OP does not say that.  He said "overflow error" in a comment, but I think he just means heap "overflow".  If he really meant `StackOverflowError`, then the problem is nothing to do with heap size, and it most likely is in code that he hasn't shown us; e.g. infinite recursion in some GUI code he hasn't shown us.

Comment: Besides a heap overflow with 1Gb is no implausible. Aren't WAV files compressed?  I expect that they would be uncompressed in memory, and depending on how the APSoundClip class works under the hood, it could require 3x the number of "words" to buffer an uncompressed clip  in memory.  If someone knew where the source code was, we could look .....

Comment: My bad... true that a `StackOverflowError` has nothing to do with the heap size. Good point with the compression too